# Are there always $2(n-1)$ ways to intersect two polygons such that these intersections are convex polygons with $3,...,2n$ vertices each?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, euclidean-geometry

Suppose two convex polygons with $n$ vertices each.

**Proposition**: There are always $2(n-1)$ ways to intersect them such that these intersections are convex polygons with $3,...,2n$ vertices each.

Is this proposition true?

Is there any theorem related to this?

I found this "fact" drawing something like this:

For $n=4$
[image: For $n=4$]

Which other conditions I have to consider for this? Like size for example.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to reject the edit? I tried to fix some spelling and the title.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot intersect these two squares to obtain an $8$-gon.
The best you can achieve is a $6$-gon (arranging the small square near
a corner of the large square).

---

[image: TwoSquares]

---

So indeed size must be taken into account.

Comment: But do you have any clue about how should I consider size?

Comment: @IvanS.Guerra: I would assume you have two identical copies of the same convex $n$-gon. Then it may be that your Proposition is true.

Comment: Where can I look for more information about this kind of things?